# SharePoint Backup and Restore

Tags: managed-metadata, backup, restore

I am just starting out experimenting with backup and restore. We have 2 farms: PRD and TST. I thought I'd begin by restoring a site collection from PRD to TST. Everything went smoothly but then I realised managed metadata was not working. It appears the Guids are different between environments. Now I'm thinking if I restore the PRD managed metadata database to TST
 that should fix the problem. Am I being naiive again? Is it as simple as that or is there a whole lot of configuration work to be done. Would I 
need to rebuild the managed metadata service from scratch? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore. I have worked it out. As usual it's a lot more complicated than I imagined. This link provided me the information I needed. http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2011/10/sharepoint-2010-how-to-backuprestore-managed-metadata-from-one-farmenvironment-to-another.html

Comment: Can you provide the answer to your problem? It may help someone else that is having the same issue.